# Some examples where the plurigenera are nonconstant, when the fibres have worse singularities than canonical

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, singularity-theory, kahler-manifolds, minimal-model-program

Let start with a definition

**Invariance of plurigenera:** Choose $m$ large enough so that $mK_F$ has a non-zero global section for some fibre $F$. For any fibre $F$, we have $K_F = K_{X/D}~_{|F}$. So deformation invariance of plurigenera says that the function

$$\dim H^0(X_p, m K_{X/D}~_{|X_p})$$
is constant on $D$ (where now $X_p$ denotes the fibre over the point $p \in D$ and $D$ is a disc).

> 1) I am lokking for examples where the plurigenera are nonconstant,
>   when the fibres have worse singularities than canonical.
>
> 2) Is there any approach for the following  conjecture?
>
> **Conjecture:** Every variety with a single pluricanonical form is birational to a variety with canonical singularities such that in
>   addition the canonical divisor is nef

Comment: With regards to (1), it sounds like you are restricting the hypothesis to be over the Complex numbers. In this case, remark 4.9 in http://arxiv.org/abs/0901.0389 may be of interest.